# How to create a object of java class in excel vba

Tags: vbscript, excel, vba

i have a java class..i have registered in my system(it has shown the message as
    registed successfully)..but when i try to create an object(the code is as below)
    It is throwing error as module not found..do i have set the path.if yes how..

```
Dim conn
set conn = createObject("Main")
```

Main is the java class which is in C:\windows\java\trustlib

Please help me out..i am new to excel vba

Answer (score 0):

See this description of [CreateObject](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_createobject.asp). Your code should look like this

```
Dim conn
Set conn = CreateObject("<server>.Main")
```

Where `<server>` is the name of the application providing the object.